# Access notes app data

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

i'm developing a notes app and I want to import all the notes stored in the default ios app into mine.
How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no API to do this. 3rd party apps have no access to such data.

Comment: A user can setup their notes to sync through an email account. Perhaps the other app accesses the notes through the email account. Either way, there is no API to even do that and there's no guarantee a user has setup their notes to sync via email.